# <div position:absolute;left:Xpx;top>… doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I have two problems with `<div position:absolute;left:Xpx;top:Ypx>` (X and Y are numbers)
the code `<div position:absolute;left:Xpx;top:Ypx>` sets the position of sentence or image or hr etc...
On my website I set my sentences using  and I set it in the center down, the problem that when I restore down my browser and resize it the position of my sentence changes!
Another problem that when I go to another PC or laptop with bigger screen (or smaller one) the sentence position changed for the center to the left!
I think the problem with the "px" parameter because when you resize your browser screen in becomes smaller the the position with px changes, same as different computer with different screen.
example for the `<div>`:

```
<div style="font-size:80%;position:absolute;l…
<p>Estimated Time Remaining Before launch:</p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how can I fix these problems?

Comment: can you plug your code into a jsFiddle so we can view the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an 'absolute' position, the element will always be positioned 'X'px from the left and 'Y' px from the top regardless of the size of your browser. If, as I'm understanding from your description, you wish for the element to always be centered the best way I've found to do this is to set its parent element (the element that it is contained within) with css styling:

```
text-align:center;
```

Then set the element you wish to center with css styling:

```
margin:0px auto;
```

The 0px refers to the margin above and below the element (Y-axis) and the auto sets the margin to the left and right of the element. Alternatively if that confuses you, you can set the individual margins as such:

```
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:0px;
```

You can set the top and bottom margins to whatever you want but must keep left and right as auto; if you wish to perfectly center the element you may want to set it as a percentage although it requires a lot of tweaking to make it work perfectly across many screen sizes.

Good Luck and hope I helped.

P.S. Must make sure the element is no longer position:absolute; instead giving it :relative; or leaving it blank

Comment: Same problem.. when I want to re size the browser page the words goes under each other (like I did <br>) and in css the sentence hides under the image that I have and I can't see the sentence anymore!

Comment: I'm not 100% certain of your problem, on re-reading it appears to me that you want the whole sentence to resize with your browser, physically getting smaller if it can't fit. Don't take my word as law but I'm pretty sure you can't do that with css and html alone, especially not html on its own. You need a fair bit of javascript if anything. Furthermore, you should be seperating the style from the HTML and putting it in the head within <style> tags.

Comment: If I am incorrect and you just wish for the sentence to be centered and stay on one line when you resize the browser you can set a fixed width for the container of the sentence, enough to fit the sentence in comfortably.